# Circuit class: constant depth, poly-size, bounded fan-in

Tags: reference-request, circuits

I'm looking for the name of a certain circuit complexity class. It captures, to me, the idea of "shallow physically feasible circuits". I'm looking for the class of problems with:

- Constant depth
- Polynomial size
- Any bounded fan-in gates (at least NOT and AND, which of course suffices for anything else)
- Some reasonable uniformity (polytime uniform? L-uniform? I don't care much)

This only makes much sense, of course, for function problems. For a language, it would mean that the output only depends on a bounded number of the input bits, which would be boring. So I'm wondering about, say, iterated addition in strange numeral systems; or questions about normalizing some representation of some object.

Apologies in advance if this is out of scope for the site, but I couldn't find it after searching myself online, and didn't know where else to ask.

Comment: Uniform NC⁰ (using a particularly strong notion of uniformity).

Comment: Functions in which each output bit depends on a bounded number of input bits are sometimes called *local*.